# How to add click event to tooltipster plugin, to hide selected elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip, tooltipster

Hello I have a few elements with class `.tooltip`. Each of them should be hidden after it's tooltip is clicked, but i don't know how to target specific element, which trigerred tooltip.

Element should be hidden after it's tooltip is clicked.

**jsfiddle demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/5r88wyfr/1/

**html**

```
<p><a href="http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/">tooltipster website</a></p>

<p class="tooltip">paragraph</p>
<b class="tooltip">bold</b>
<div class="tooltip">div</div>
<a class="tooltip" href="#">anchor</a><br>
<span class="tooltip">span</span>
```

**css**

```
.tooltip {
    margin: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.tooltipster-default {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tooltipster-default:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**js**

```
$("*").tooltipster({
    content: $('<span>hide this element</span>'),
    interactive: true,
    onlyOne: true,
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize your tooltip on each element one at the time. use .each()-method for that. Here is a [JS-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Salmin/5r88wyfr/2/)

```
$(".tooltip").each(function(){
    $(this).tooltipster({
        content: $('<span>hide this element</span>'),
        interactive: true,
        onlyOne: true,
        functionReady: function(origin, tooltip) {
            tooltip.on("click", function() {
                origin.hide();
            });
        }
    });
})
```